# before_update not working correctly with Ajax, Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Users have points based on the number of Milestones they complete. I have a list of Milestones that users complete using Ajax and the Milestone points should be added on to the User's points.

The database updates correctly and refreshing the page updates correctly, however rendering the partial after the Ajax call does not.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the `before_update` callback, but can't figure it out for the life of me.

**controller** *milestones_controller.rb*

```
def update
  @milestone = Milestone.find(params[:id])
  if @milestone.update_attributes(complete: true)
    flash.now[:notice] = "You completed #{@milestone.title} for #{@milestone.points} points!"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to current_user }
      format.js { render :action => "milestones" }
    end
  else
    redirect_to current_user
    flash[:alert] = "Not working"
  end
end
```

**js** *milestones.js.erb*

```
$('.user_points').html('<%=  escape_javascript(render :partial => 'users/partials/user_points') %>');
```

**model** *milestone.rb*

```
before_update :add_user_points, if: :complete_changed?

private

  def add_user_points
    user = User.friendly.find(user_id)
    user.update(points: user.points + self.points)
  end
```

**partial and view** *users/partials/_user_points.html.erb*

```
<%= pluralize(@user.points, "point") %>
```

*users/show.html.erb*

```
<div class="user_points">
  <%= render 'users/partials/user_points' %>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your web server console say when you click on the AJAX link?

Comment: Everything renders perfectly (I've omitted the other partials for simplicity). The points actually update in the database to the correct amount, but fails to render correctly in the partial on the first commit. Refreshing the page will show the correct amount as well. Does the `before_update` get called after the render? I'm not sure that even makes sense.

Comment: I ask because I was wondering if you see the JS partial update come across the web console when you hit save. This would at least tell you if the browser is being sent the partial update. If the browser is receiving the new partial and not rendering it that is important to know in the trouble shooting process.

Comment: Oh, yes, the partial is rendering in the browser according to the console.

Comment: Ok, so you are sure the browser is getting and rendering the new version of your partial. I deleted my first answer because it was addressing that. Your problem has to be that the `@user` variable still contains the old info. You don't show in your code where you define the `@user` variable. You probably need to refresh your `@user` data before rendering the partial.

Comment: Yup, it's definitely working. I set up Ajax for creating milestones as well and used `count` to update the number each time I created one in the same partial as the points and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a ajax file that do not match with name of method. Here, you have `update` method but you use `milestone.js.erb` file.

You have to change several parts here.

**Controller**

You have to edit your format js.

```
def update
  @milestone = Milestone.find(params[:id])
  if @milestone.update_attributes(complete: true)
    flash.now[:notice] = "You completed #{@milestone.title} for #{@milestone.points} points!"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to current_user }
      format.js
    end
  else
    redirect_to current_user
    flash[:alert] = "Not working"
  end
end
```

Then, you have to change your `milestones.js.erb` into `update.js.erb`. I hope this help you.

Comment: Looking at some of my AJAX code I was starting down this same path. I think you are right. The `{ render :action => "milestones" }` caught my eye and had me thinking "where is the milestones action?".

Comment: You are right. I thought it shows nothing to do with `milestones` in `update` method.